# finding info in text file using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Wondering if you can help.

I have a series of (~950KB) '.txt' output files from a computational chemistry program. Each has the following general format:

```
Job Started  at 15:45.50 12th June       2013
```

...

```
 **** Optimisation achieved ****

 Final energy =    -348.67740315 eV
 Final Gnorm  =       0.00037832
```

...

```
 **** Optimisation achieved ****

 Final defect energy  =      103.09066596
 Final defect Gnorm   =        0.00000141
```

...

**[N.B. This second optimisation may not always be achieved, but a 'defect energy' will be printed anyway: if this is the case I am not interested in the result as it is meaningless]**

**[N.B. The number of lines represented by the dots varies form file to file and is unknown until the file is read. Also they are not numbered.]**

My task is to find the lines shown above and output them into a newly created 'results' file.

I know how to open and read the file, but am unsure as to how to go about finding/copying the above lines from each file within the directory.

Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated (please be patient I am new to programming)

Comment: Does the data have some structure?

Comment: @badc0re Each of the iterative optimisation steps gets its own line - like a table (but not one). The energies that I am after, are explicitly stated on their own line at the end of the calculation. (Thankfully the code that I use to run the calculations is semi user friendly in that respect.)

Comment: It would help to show the code to make answering your question a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, you could do something like this

```
def find_energy(fn):
    lines = open(fn).readlines()
    result_lines = [l for l in lines if '*optimisation achieved**' in l]
    print(fn, result_lines)
```

But you will need to modify it to fit your data and the exact output format that you want

Comment: apologies but could you explain the ones in the brackets of result_lines?

Comment: That's a so-called list comprehension. This line generates a list of all the lines containing '*optimisation achieved**'.
More info here:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Question isn't for 100% clear for me but from these parts I can understand it isn't complex task.

I can propose you function to read all your files and print output data in format:

> (filename, final energy, defect energy)

This function will work only if in each file you will provide will be one occurrence of "final energy" and one occurrence of "defect energy".

To make this function work you have to call if with list of files to be parsed. Whole data will be stored into output file or printing to stdout.

```
def get_data_by_pattern(filenames, output_file=None, text_pattern='optimisation achieved'):
try:
    ofh = open(output_file, 'w+')
except (IOError, OSError):
    ofh = sys.stdout
for f_name in filenames:
    try:
        filedata = open(f_name, 'r').read()
    except (IOError, OSError), err:
        print 'Problem with file "%s": %s' % (f_name, err)
        continue
    final_energy = ''
    defect_energy = ''
    for l in b.splitlines():
        if text_pattern in l:
            if 'final' in l:
                final_energy = l.split('=')[1]
            elif 'defect' in l:
                defect_energy = l.split('=')[1]
        if final_energy and defect_energy:
            break
    ofh.write('(%s,%s,%s)\n' % (filename, final_energy, defect_energy))
```